# Why my URL routing does not work?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-routing

In application start of the global.asax i have

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
 End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
  routes.MapPageRoute("contactform", "{locale}/contact", "~/general/ContactUs.aspx")
End Sub
```

the strange that is goimg on, is that when i visit the webpage directly

```
~/general/contactus.aspx
```

everything works like a charm, but when i visit the page indirectly

```
~/en/contact
```

a 404 error is returned! Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be related to multiple things. What I would first look at is that :

Make sure that your application is running under IIS 7.0 or +.

Make sure that your application is running under an integrated mode app pool inside IIS 7 or IIS 7.5.

Make sure that you have the following code inside your web.config file :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

> Not sure though but the above code shouldn't be necessary on IIS 7.5.
>   This should be already configured for IIS 7.5 out of the box.